# sed: remove all characters except for last n characters

Tags: bash, macos, unix, sed, text-processing

I am trying to remove every character in a text string except for the remaining 11 characters. The string is `Sample Text_that-would$normally~be,here--pe_-l4_mBY` and what I want to end up with is just `-pe_-l4_mBY`.

Here's what I've tried:

```
$ cat food
Sample Text_that-would$normally~be,here--pe_-l4_mBY
$ cat food | sed 's/^.*(.{3})$/\1/'
sed: 1: "s/^.*(.{3})$/\1/": \1 not defined in the RE
```

Please note that the text string isn't really stored in a file, I just used `cat food` as an example.

OS is macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 and `bash` version is 3.2.57(1)-release

Comment: Improved example, didn't realise i put 10 characters instead of 11 :-/

Comment: Use `cat food | sed 's/^.*\(.\{11\}\)$/\1/'` if you need a BRE POSIX pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this `sed` with a capture group:

```
sed -E 's/.*(.{11})$/\1/' file
```

```
-pe_-l4_mBY
```

Answer (score 3):

Basic regular expressions (used by default by `sed`) require both the parentheses in the capture group and the braces in the brace expression to be escaped. `(` and `{` are otherwise treated as literal characters to be matched.

```
$ cat food | sed 's/^.*\(.\{3\}\)$/\1/'
mBY
```

By contrast, explicitly requesting `sed` to use extended regular expressions with the `-E` option reverses the meaning, with `\(` and `\{` being the literal characters.

```
$ cat food | sed -E 's/^.*(.{3})$/\1/'
mBY
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this also:

```
grep -o -E '.{11}$' food
```

`grep`, like `sed`, accepts an arbitrary number of file name arguments, so there is no need for a separate `cat`. (See also [useless use of `cat`.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Answer (score 1):

You can use tail or Parameter Expansion :

```
string='Sample Text_that-would$normally~be,here--pe_-l4_mBY'
echo "$string" | tail -c 11
echo "${string#${string%??????????}}"

pe_-l4_mBY
pe_-l4_mBY
```

Answer (score -1):

also with `rev/cut/rev`

```
$ echo abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | rev | cut -c1-11 | rev 

pqrstuvwxyz
```

`man rev` => `rev - reverse lines characterwise`